# AsynchronousSocketChannel not reading in entire message

Tags: java, sockets, nio, serversocket, nio2

When I run the below locally (on my own computer) it works fine - I can send messages to it and it reads them in properly. As soon as I put this on a remote server and send a message, only half the message gets read.

```
try {
            this.asynchronousServerSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(80));
            this.asynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept(null, new CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel asynchronousSocketChannel, Void att) {
                    try {
                        asynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept(null, this);
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10485760);
                        asynchronousSocketChannel.read(byteBuffer).get(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        byteBuffer.flip();
                        System.out.println("request: " + Charset.defaultCharset().decode(byteBuffer).toString());

                    } catch (CorruptHeadersException | CorruptProtocolException | MalformedURLException ex) {

                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable exc, Void att) {
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

I've looked around at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698689/how-to-read-a-request-using-completionhandlers-and-a-bytebuffer-smaller-than-the) and tried some of the answers but nothing worked so far. I thought the cause might be that it's timing out due to it being slower over the network when it's placed remotely but increasing the timeout didn't resolve the issue. I also considered that the message might be too large but allocating more capacity to the `ByteBuffer` didn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte stream protocol. If you want mssages you have to implement them yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a browser which I believe sends across a `byte[]`, bad choice of words on my part

Comment: Same difference. 'Message' == 'byte array' in this case. It's a byte stream protocol. There is nothing that says will receive the entire sent byte array in a single operation.

Comment: @EJP: I'm not too familiar with the NIO2 framework and can't seem to find a good source of information on the topic. Any recommendations?

Comment: This is a basic property of TCP. It has nothing to do with NIO2 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize lambda functions when receiving data from asynchronous socket. Herein the read completion handler is created using standalone method `newReadHandler(...)` with lambda functions as parameters. The asynchronous reading is started with `readLambda.accept(handler);` statement placed at the end of the following Java code. The `completed(...)` callback method is invoked asynchronously so that algorithm doesn't collect function calls on the stack.

```
private CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole> newReadHandler(
                BiFunction<Integer, LogConsole, Boolean> completedLambda,
                BiConsumer<Throwable, LogConsole> failedLambda,
                Consumer<CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole>> nextReadLambda) {
    
    CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole> completionHandler = new CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(Integer result, LogConsole console) {
            if (!completedLambda.apply(result, console)) 
                return;
            nextReadLambda.accept(newReadHandler(completedLambda, failedLambda, nextReadLambda));
        }
        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exception, LogConsole console) {
            failedLambda.accept(exception, console);
        }
    };
    return completionHandler;
}

public readFromClientSocket(AsynchronousSocketChannel socket) {
    BiFunction<Integer, LogConsole, Boolean> completedLambda = (readResult, readConsole) -> {
        // Accept successful read operation.
    };
    BiConsumer<Throwable, LogConsole> failedLambda = (readException, readConsole) -> {
        // Read exception.
    };
    Consumer<CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole>> readLambda = (handler) -> {
        // Read operation.
        socket.read(console.inputBuffer, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, console, handler);
    };
    // Create completion handler.
    CompletionHandler<Integer, LogConsole> handler = newReadHandler(completedLambda, failedLambda, readLambda);
    // Run first read operation with firt completion handler. 
    readLambda.accept(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with the Asynchronous nature of the code you're using. What you have is an open connection and you've called the asynchronous `read` method on your socket. 
This reads `n` bytes from the channel where `n` is anything from `0` to the size of your available buffer.

I firmly believe that you have to read in a loop. That is, with Java's A-NIO; you'd need to call `read` again from your `completed` method on your `CompletionHandler` by, possibly, passing in the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` as an attachment to a new `completed` method on a `CompletionHandler` you create for `read` , not the one you already have for `accept` methods.

I think this is the same sort of pattern you'd use where you'd call `accept` again with `this` as the completion handler from your `completed` method in the `CompletionHandler` you're using for the `accept` method call.

It then becomes important to put an "Escape" clause into your `CompletionHandler` for instance, if the `result` is `-1` or if the `ByteBuffer` had read `X` number of bytes based on what you're expecting, or based on if the final `byte` in the `ByteBuffer` is a specific message termination byte that you've agreed with the sending application.

The [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler)) on the matter goes so far as to say the `read` method will only read the amount of bytes on the `dst` at the time of invocation.

In Summary; the `completed` method call for the handler for the `read` seems to execute once something was written to the channel; but if something is being streamed you could get half of the bytes, so you'd need to continue reading until you're satisfied you've got the end of what they were sending.

Below is some code I knocked together on reading until the end, responding whilst reading, asynchronously. It, unlike myself, can talk and listen at the same time.

```
public class ReadForeverCompletionHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Pair<AsynchronousSocketChannel, ByteBuffer>> {
@Override
public void completed(Integer bytesRead, Pair<AsynchronousSocketChannel, ByteBuffer> statefulStuff) {
    if(bytesRead != -1) {
        final ByteBuffer receivedByteBuffer = statefulStuff.getRight();
        final AsynchronousSocketChannel theSocketChannel = statefulStuff.getLeft();
        if (receivedByteBuffer.position()>8) {
            //New buffer as existing buffer is in use
            ByteBuffer response = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedByteBuffer.array());
            receivedByteBuffer.clear(); //safe as we've not got any outstanding or in progress reads, yet.
            theSocketChannel.read(receivedByteBuffer,statefulStuff,this); //Basically "WAIT" on more data
            Future<Integer> ignoredBytesWrittenResult = theSocketChannel.write(response);
        }
    }
    else {
        //connection was closed code
        try {
            statefulStuff.getLeft().shutdownOutput(); //maybe
        }
        catch (IOException somethingBad){
            //fire
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void failed(Throwable exc, Pair<AsynchronousSocketChannel, ByteBuffer> attachment) {
    //shout fire
}
```

The read is originally kicked off by a call from the `completed` method in the handler from the very original asynchronous `accept` on the server socket like

```
public class AcceptForeverCompletionHandler implements CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Pair<AsynchronousServerSocketChannel, Collection<AsynchronousSocketChannel>>> {

private final ReadForeverCompletionHandler readForeverAndEverAndSoOn = new ReadForeverCompletionHandler();

@Override
public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel result, Pair<AsynchronousServerSocketChannel, Collection<AsynchronousSocketChannel>> statefulStuff) {
    statefulStuff.getLeft().accept(statefulStuff, this); //Accept more new connections please as we go
    statefulStuff.getRight().add(result); //Collect these in case we want to for some reason, I don't know
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4098); //4k seems a nice number
    result.read(buffer, Pair.of(result, buffer ),readForeverAndEverAndSoOn); //Kick off the read "forever"
}

@Override
public void failed(Throwable exc, Pair<AsynchronousServerSocketChannel, Collection<AsynchronousSocketChannel>> attachment) {
    //Shout fire
}
```

}